# Помощь с бранчами и merge

Tags: git

У меня есть два бранча в папке с проектом Company. Company - это проект visual studio, один брэнч main другой Secbranch предположим я хочу добавить файл temp.txt из вообще другой папки (например из папки App1) в бранч Secbranch, но если я в папке App1 нажимаю git bash here, то там я естественно не обнаружу своих бранчей, а если я выполню git init, то я создам там новый локальный репозиторий. Как мне это сделать и как потом выполнить merge, понятное дело, что выполнить мерж можно git checkout main, git merge Secbranch, но проблема как раз в том, что если я нахожусь в папке App1, то там нет ни Secbranch не нужного мне main. Наверное мне нужно в папке App1 сделать pull, но как правильно указать из какого удалённого репозитория пулить?

Comment: Пройди [этот](https://githowto.com/ru) интерактивный тренажер по git.

Comment: вам, действительно, стоит ознакомиться с теорией: чем же в действительности является программа git, какими сущностями она манипулирует, что такое хранилище (репозиторий), что такое рабочий каталог (которого может при хранилище и не быть), что такое ветка. // судя по изложенному в тексте вопроса, у вас (надеюсь, пока) наблюдается непонимание этих базовых сущностей.

Comment: не знаю, я понимаю что такое ветка, что такое репозиторий. что он бывает локальный и ремоут, что делает пуш то делает пулл, я знаю как создавать ветки, как коммитить, как делать merge в общем случае, если не возникнет каких-то проблем, ибо я в этом new, если я прочту про алиасы как делать коммиты, как их откатывать и прочее ещё несколько раз, мне кажется ума у меня не добавится, я конечно попробую ещё раз прочитать)

Comment: Книга ProGit в открытом доступе. Читайте, там всё разжёвано очень хорошо.